# Jest: Multiple inline snapshots for the same call are not supported

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

getting this error ONLY when using the code inside an `it.each` block

deleteMe.tsx:

```
export const deleteMe = (inputVal: string): string =>
  `this is function returning: ${inputVal}`;
```

deleteMe.test.tsx:

```
import { deleteMe } from './deleteMe';
describe('simplest string matching', () => {
  it.each([['one'], ['two'], ['three'], ['four'], ['five'], ['six']])(
    'matches snapshot fox input %s',
    (inputVal) => {
      expect(deleteMe(inputVal)).toMatchInlineSnapshot(
        `this is function returning: ${inputVal}`,
      );
    },
  );
});
```

running `yarn test -u` returns the error below:

[image]

note:

- if you run one test at a time instead of `it.each`, the snapshots are updated ok
- if you use `toMatchSnapshot` instead of `toMatchInlineSnapshot`, the snapshots are updated ok
- this is a recent problem, faced after updating the following packages:

  - "react": "18.2.0",
  - "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.16.5",
  - "jest-environment-jsdom": "29.4.0",
  - "jest-fetch-mock": "3.0.3",
    trying to find the best way here

Comment: Remove all snapshot testing.

Comment: See https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6636